# flutter firebase user sign in on app start

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

In the splash screen I  want to check if there is an authenticated user to navigate to the home page 
and if not go the signup/ login page
here's my code for the splash screen the method starts and check if there's a user loged in then navigate to home if there's a user loged in

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseUser _user;
Future<FirebaseUser> _getUser() async {
_user = await _auth.currentUser();
return _user;
}

Future startTime() async {
var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 2);
return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage());
}

navigationPage() {
  if (_user != null) {
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
  } else {
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/welcome');
  }
}

@override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _getUser();
 startTime();
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new Center(
      child: new Image.asset(
      'assets/imgs/logo.png',
        width: 162.0,
      height: 58.0,
     ),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @aziza there's a user logged in and when I print to the console I get the user id and all of his information but I still get navigated to sign in / sign up page

Comment: Have you tried calling `setState((){})` before `return _user`

Comment: yes, I tried. I solve it by getting the  _user inside the ' startTime' function, and it worked, thanks for your help

Comment: @OsamaGamal Then, please provide an answer or delete your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve it by getting the _user inside the ' startTime' function, and it worked

```
Future startTime() async {
_user = await _auth.currentUser();
var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 2);
return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage());
}
```